# Magento: Redirect customer to third-party payment site

Tags: php, magento, checkout

I'm currently creating my first custom checkout page in Magento. I've got a code that works - it creates an unpaid order, so the next step is to redirect the customer to the third-party payment site based on the selected payment method.

After some research it seems like there's a parameter called **redirectUrl** which I should be able to get somehow, but I can't really figure out how.

If I'm all wrong then please point me back on track! Thank you in advance.

```
<?php
    require_once 'app/Mage.php';

    Mage::app();

    $quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore('default')->getId());

    // guest order
    $quote->setCustomerEmail('customer@example.com');

    // add sample product
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(8);
    $buyInfo = array(
            'qty' => 1,
    );
    $quote->addProduct($product, new Varien_Object($buyInfo));

    $addressData = array(
            'firstname' => 'Test',
            'lastname' => 'Test',
            'street' => 'Sample Street 10',
            'city' => 'Somewhere',
            'postcode' => '123456',
            'telephone' => '123456',
            'country_id' => 'SE'
    );

    $billingAddress = $quote->getBillingAddress()->addData($addressData);
    $shippingAddress = $quote->getShippingAddress()->addData($addressData);

    $shippingAddress->setCollectShippingRates(true)->collectShippingRates()->setShippingMethod('flatrate_flatrate')->setPaymentMethod('checkmo');

    $quote->getPayment()->importData(array('method' => 'checkmo'));

    $quote->collectTotals()->save();

    $service = Mage::getModel('sales/service_quote', $quote);
    $service->submitAll();
    $order = $service->getOrder();

    echo 'Created order #' . $order->getIncrementId();
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

In the sample code you are using Magento classes into a standalone PHP file. In this way, Magento redirects will not work, since it is a method from `Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action`. You have to be using Magento controllers to try this redirect way.

Anyway, you can use the PHP [header](http://php.net/header) function: `header("Location: http://somepayment.com/complexUrl"); die;`

Comment: But how can I fetch the URL for the payment method?

Comment: Are you referring to get the URL from Payment Method Config section in Administration?

Comment: No, the URL from the selected payment method ("checkmo" in the sample).